# Count rows from another table matching 2 ids and after a date in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in Postgresql 13 with the following sample structure:

```
table1
-------
client_id
member_id
email_count
last_date

table2
-------
client_id
member_id
created_at
```

Im trying to update the email_count column for each record in table1 with a count of rows from table2 where the client_id, member_id match and the created_at date is > than the last_date column.

Ive tried multiple approaches but cant seem to get the right combination. My latest approach using a CTE looks like:

```
with counted as (
select t.client_id,
       t.member_id,
       t.last_date,
       (select count(*)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.client_id = t.client_id
          and t2.member_id = t.member_id
          and t2.created_at > t.last_engagement_date
       ) as count
from (
     select t1.client_id,
            t1.member_id,
            t1.last_date
    from table1 t1
         ) t
)
update table1
set email_count = counted.count
where table1.client_id = counted.client_id
and table1.member_id = counted.member_id;
```

But all of the counts are coming up as zero. Ive verified the data and should be getting counts as high as 200 in some cases.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**EDIT**
Example structure with additional data from first answer:

```
create table table1 (
client_id int,
member_id int,
email_count int,
last_date date
);

create table table2 (
client_id int,
member_id int,
created_at date
);

insert into table1
values (1, 1, null, '2021-06-01')
,(2, 3, null, '2021-05-01')
,(2, 4, null, '2021-04-01');

insert into table2
values (1, 1, '2021-05-01')
,(1, 1, '2021-07-01')
,(2, 3, '2021-06-01')
,(2, 3, '2021-07-01')
,(2, 4, '2021-04-01')
,(2, 4, '2021-05-01')
,(2, 4, '2021-06-01')
,(2, 4, '2021-07-01');
```

From this data Im expecting to get the following results in the email_count field:

```
client_id|member_id|email_count
   1     |    1    |    1
   2     |    3    |    2
   2     |    4    |    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws errors on dbfiddle.

This would be easier with a working fiddle to start with, including sample data.

```
create table table1 (
client_id int,
member_id int,
email_count int,
last_date date
);

create table table2 (
client_id int,
member_id int,
created_at date
);

insert into table1
values (1, 1, null, '2021-06-01');

insert into table2
values (1, 1, '2021-05-01')
, (1, 1, '2021-07-01');


update table1
set email_count = t2.email_count
from (
select count(table1.*) email_count
from table1
  inner join table2 on table2.client_id = table1.client_id
                   and table2.member_id = table1.member_id
                   and table2.created_at > table1.last_date
) t2
;

select *
from table1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=71d887b17cd91793a719786ed829b58d

Comment: Ive updated my question with more sample data and expected results. Based on your fiddle, the UPDATE doesnt seem to be counting the rows from table 2 that match? When running that UPDATE against more data it sets email_count for all rows in table1 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to update in `postgresql`.

```
UPDATE 
    table1
SET 
    email_count = result.count
FROM 
    (select t.client_id,
       t.member_id,
       t.email_count,
       t.last_date,
       (select count(*)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.client_id = t.client_id
          and t2.member_id = t.member_id
          and t2.created_at > t.last_date) as count
from (
     select t1.client_id,
            t1.member_id,
            t1.email_count,
            t1.last_date
      from table1 t1) t) result
where table1.client_id = result.client_id and table1.member_id = result.member_id
```

Use the same name cte to update with cte because it is in the source table in `sql`

```
with counted as (
      select t.client_id,
       t.member_id,
       t.email_count,
       t.last_date,
       (select count(*)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.client_id = t.client_id
          and t2.member_id = t.member_id
          and t2.created_at > t.last_date) as count
       from (
     select t1.client_id,
            t1.member_id,
            t1.email_count,
            t1.last_date
    from table1 t1
         ) t)        
update counted
set email_count = counted.count;
```

Comment: And Postgres needs the statement termination character `;` at the _end_ of the statement not at the beginning

Comment: @user16435057 I updated the code and it will produce the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this is so easy to query...

```
select table2.client_id
, table2.member_id
, count(table2.*) email_count
from table1
  inner join table2 on table2.client_id = table1.client_id
                   and table2.member_id = table1.member_id
                   and table2.created_at > table1.last_date
group by table2.client_id
, table2.member_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0df6cef6916a321d97669fd4d0cec63

...why would you need to persist the value in `email_count`?  That's a form of duplication that, if there isn't a reason to persist the data to improve system performance, you may not want.

Comment: We wouldnt necessarily need to persist it, but querying it takes a long time for some reason. Table1 has about 7M rows and Table2 has about 220M rows. Indexes on the member_id and client_id columns on both tables as well. And your select query above has been running for over 10 minutes already. Our DB server has 32 cores and 190GB of ram so its got plenty of resources too.